# Passing arguments to ajax within a generic function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This is making me crazy:

I can successfully pass arguments into this function, and display them in an alert. I can also populate the div by id, if I define the values in the function.

```
function getStuff( req, elementid ) {
  //var req = 'slider';
  //var elementid = '#slider';

  //var req = 'thumbnails';
 //var elementid = '#thumbnails';
  $.ajax({
      async: false,
      url: '/update',
      contentType: 'text/html',
      data: { putski: req },
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: "html",
      success: function(stuff) {
              $( elementid ).html(stuff);
              alert(req+elementid)
   },

   error: function( xhr, status, errorThrown ) {
        alert( "Sorry, there was a problem!" );
        ( "Error: " + errorThrown );
        console.log( "Status: " + status );
        console.dir( xhr );
   },

   complete: function( xhr, status ) {
        return false;
   }

  });
};

$(document).ready( getStuff( 'thumbnails', '#thumbnails' ) );  // alert shows    thumbnails#thumbnails but div does not populate.
```

**The following variation is populating and should rule out issues other than the one I've described.**

```
function getStuff( req, elementid ) {
  var req = 'slider';                  //uncomment these definitions and the div populates
  var elementid = '#slider';

  //var req = 'thumbnails';
  //var elementid = '#thumbnails';
  $.ajax({
      async: false,
      url: '/update',
      contentType: 'text/html',
      data: { putski: req },
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: "html",
      success: function(stuff) {
              $( elementid ).html(stuff);
              alert(req+elementid)
   },

   error: function( xhr, status, errorThrown ) {
        alert( "Sorry, there was a problem!" );
        ( "Error: " + errorThrown );
        console.log( "Status: " + status );
        console.dir( xhr );
   },

   complete: function( xhr, status ) {
        return false;
   }

  });
};

$(document).ready( getStuff );  // populated using the values defined at the top.
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: Have you looked at the value of "stuff" in the first example? And btw, the function is being called before document ready fires, not sure if on purpose.

Comment: I can alert() the value of 'stuff' and it shows the html returned from the back end.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing apples to oranges

In the second version, you can try the following:

```
var req = 'thumbnails';                
var elementid = '#thumbnails';
```

If this doesn't work then you know that either the server code is not dealing with the "thumbnails" parameter correctly, or the element id "#thumbnails" is not defined.  I doubt that the problem is with passing the parameters vs. setting them in the function.

Comment: $(document).ready( getStuff( 'thumbnails', '#thumbnails' ) );  
alert shows thumbnails#thumbnails but div does not populate.

Comment: That's not it. I just uncommented the wrong one in my example. Both 'slider' and 'thumbnails' are correctly defined in the html and the server responses are fine, evidenced by the fact it does work when I define them in the function. 

The really weird this is that they make it to the alert when I pass them in as arguments, but the div just doesn't populate.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I fixed it but I have to admit, I don't really understand the behavior. I commented out "async: false," and it started working with the thumbnails. I added that line in the first place because the slider doesn't work without it. :p Maybe someone could shed some light on this?